# Domino Server is installed on Unix or Windows?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus, lotus-domino

Can someone please let me know How to programmatically find out whether the Domino server is installed on Unix or Windows.

Is there any Domino server API to find out in which OS(OS related information) the domino server is running.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the formula [@Platform](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_PLATFORM_FUNCTION.html) function for this.

> When it is used in column, selection, or scheduled agent formulas,
>   @Platform returns the current platform where the database resides. *If
>   the database resides on a server, @Platform returns the server
>   platform;* if the database resides locally, @Platform returns the
>   workstation platform.

Answer (score 2):

If you open the main Domino Directory on the server ( names.nsf ) and look at the server/servers view you will see a list of all the Domino servers that are setup. Each record contains a reference to the OS that is running the server.

Answer (score 1):

In LotusScript or with the COM classes, use NotesSession.Platform().  In Java, use Session.getPlatform().  Note that in either case, your code must be running on the actual server that you are testing.